# Beginning NSMutableArray - Debug ignored

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsmutablearray

I am just learning objective-c.  Hopefully this is a simple fix for anyone that has worked with NSMutableArrays before.

Note: I have watched 3 videos on you tube and read 5 articles before asking this question.  There are plenty of resources available for the setValue:forKey, but I don't believe that applies to this scenario.

I am trying to use a simple array to support the selections made in a tic tac toe game.  The concept is simple:
- the array is instantiated with 9 array nodes
- when a selection is made the current letter will be placed in the corresponding array node
- the method to check for the end of a game will reference the array nodes.

Problems:
- I tried to set `NSNull` values instead of `@""` for each default object.  I get an error of `"Unexpected interface name 'NSNull'`.
- The NSLog logic to debug array nodes never executes.  My assumption is the array is not being populated.

```
@synthesize lblStatus, currLetter;
@synthesize selections;
@synthesize btn0, btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4, btn5, btn6, btn7, btn8;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [selections initWithObjects:
     @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", nil];

    currLetter = @"X";
    [self updateTitle];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (IBAction)takeTurn:(id)sender {
    UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)sender;
    if (btn.currentTitle == nil) {
        [selections replaceObjectAtIndex:btn.tag withObject:currLetter];
        [sender setTitle:currLetter forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self changeTurns];
    }
}

- (void)changeTurns {

    if ([currLetter isEqualToString:@"X"]) {
        currLetter = @"O";
    } else {
        currLetter = @"X";
    }

    for (NSString *node in selections) {
        NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"Node: %@", node]);
    }

    [self updateTitle];
}

- (void)updateTitle {
    [lblStatus setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@'s Turn", currLetter]];
}
```

If you see something else that is considered "bad code" I'll gladly take that feedback also.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Never call an `-init` method without first calling `+alloc`, like this: `[[Foo alloc] init]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `[selections initWithObjects:
     @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", nil];`

write `selections = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:
     @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", nil];`

Comment: Worked perfectly!  Thank you very much for the quick response.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding [NSNull null] on to that array. You could add null objects inside the array instead of empty strings

Best Regards

Comment: What difference do you expect this to make, and why?

Comment: Tapping on the same button will keep change the turn. One more validation needs to be added. If you add null objects inside the array while user taps on a button check whether that object is kind of a class [NSNull class]. If no, don't change the turn and let the user to select or else continue your implementation

Comment: I appreciate the feedback, and I agree the NSNull is the approach I wanted to use originally.  The software is not reacting as you describe, though.  Tapping on the same button will be ignored once the title has been applied (X or O).